# static string to be part of regex pattern

Tags: regex

It might sound a weird request and I totally understand that this is not the purpose of regex. I am just looking for a possible workaround or a feature that is less used / documented (if any)

The scenario is I can provide a regex as an admin for configuring an option where a file / web service response is parsed for matches and same is returned to end user; (Application and other details don't seem to be important but if you are interested please let me know.)

Now is it possible that I specify a string in the pattern that is not considered from matching but is returned with the match. like

[String :] [regex pattern]

and now the regex engine ignores the [string] and for matches returns

[String : match1] [String : match2] [String : match3] ...

Comment: If the engine supports lookbehinds, that's usually what you'd go for, otherwise, using capture groups and using only the captured part(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a suffix added to all the lines matched with a regex then you can try something like the following,

The following command adds the string "**STRING**" to all the matched lines,

```
grep -w "Your_Pattern" Your_FILE | sed -e 's/^/STRING/'
```